# JQuery increase div size on hover

Tags: jquery, css

When user hovers div this div increases size. But how to  decrease size when user removes cursor from this div.

```
var hoveredDiv;
        $('.promoContent').hover(function () {
            hoveredDiv = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#' + hoveredDiv).animate({height: '100%'});
        });
```

Comment: use, `$(selector).mouseenter({ ... }).mouseleave({ ... });`

Comment: Why in hell would you use js instead of css for this simple hover situation? And why in hell you get the element's id to select it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave
>   events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during
>   the time the mouse is within the element.

```
$('.promoContent').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({height: '100%'});
},function(){
      $(this).animate({height: '50%'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use mouseover and mouseout events.

http://jsfiddle.net/xno5hb34/1/

```
<button class="promoContent" id="hoveredDiv" style="width:30%; height: 60%; background-color: red">MouseOverToIncreaseSize</button>

var hoveredDiv;
    $('.promoContent').mouseover(function () {
        hoveredDiv = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + hoveredDiv).animate({ height: (parseInt($('#' + hoveredDiv).css("height").trim('px')) * 2) + "px" });
    });

    $('.promoContent').mouseout(function () {
        hoveredDiv = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + hoveredDiv).animate({ height: (parseInt($('#' + hoveredDiv).css("height").trim('px')) / 2) + "px" });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var hoveredDiv;
    $('.promoContent').hover(function () {
        hoveredDiv = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + hoveredDiv).animate({"height": "100%"});
    });
```

> $('#' + hoveredDiv).animate({"height": "100%"});

Just add double qute ( " " )

> "height": "100%"